# Are there any common, simple java logic libraries for making code more readable?

Tags: java, apache, logic

hi guys : does anyone know if there is a common apache or other logic library for simplifying code blocks ?  For example, to handle logical questions such as (isOneOf, containsNOf, ...)  ?

Im not looking for something too fancy, or experimental, but rather, a simple java library with apis that make my code read more functionally .

Comment: What kind of APIs? You allude to collection APIs but without knowing what exactly you're after it's hard to suggest anything!

Comment: @berry120 : Collections are fundamental to most of the logic that one would want to apply in programming, so, in that sense, they are important.  In general, I want to remove boiler plate that exists in complex if/switch statements --- without having to write new methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java.util.Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) has contains, containsAll, size, retainAll, removeAll. Without knowing precisely what you're after, it's hard to answer more precisely. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) also has excellent collection utilities (predicates, etc.), and some additional useful collections.

Comment: I dont want to be restricted to any one particular data structure, rather, I wanted a set of static logic methods, etc...   But I think you are correct that Guava might be more relevant.  Thanks !!!!!!!!